# angular material Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering page issue

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I am trying to follow Angular Material Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering from this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples).

Everything seems to work OK but I am being block by the following.
Do you guys know how to fix this?
It does not happen on Firefox but it happens on chrome or chromium.

In case if you need the version no

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.4.6
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.4.6
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

[image: Dancing pagination]

Answer (score 1):

Adding Theme fixes my issue.

As guided [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme)

I put the following in style.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

It is now working as expected.